# Is it safe to ignore the warning: Value stored in delayTimer is never read?

Tags: objective-c, warnings, nstimer

This is how my code looks currently

```
NSTimer *delayTimer;
delayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(longRunner)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];

// [delayTimer invalidate];
```

If I run this through build and analyze I get the following warning

> Value stored in delayTimer is never read.

I understand the message and what it means but can't really figure out how to stop it appearing.  Are there some analyzer messages ok to ignore?

I tried adding the commented invalidate code, but as expected this ran before the timer so the timer didn't.

Comment: You need to do a better job of categorizing your question if you want it to be found by the people who can answer it. Georg has given it a better title but could you tag it with the language/programming environment you are using instead of the current unhelpful tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is never a good idea to ignore warnings.  You have two options in this case:

1. Store the timer in a property.  This is the better option as it allows you to destroy the timer if the object that created it is destroyed before the timer fires.
2. Don't create a local variable.  This is the actual warning.  Since you are not using the pointer 'delayTimer' then just don't assign it.

Option 1 is the right answer.  Option 2 will remove the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe, it only warns you that your value not got readed in your script.

Like php warns you with:

> Notice: Undefined variable:

Still you should probably invalidate your timer somewhere in your code unless it has to run until you quit the application.

Comment: What I am attempting to do is control the flow in an iPhone application to display an activity view.  The delaytimer is the last line in the method.  does this mean I need a new property for the timer so I can reference it from longrunner, or is there a better way